# Launching 'data;' titled tab in second tab in automation along with hit url in first tab

Tags: java, selenium

"data;" titled tab is launching in second tab in automation along with the tab of hitted url via driver.get() in first tab. I've updated the chrome browser version and also downloaded the latest version chrome driver as per the chrome  browser version. My chrome browser version is 77.0.3865.75 and downloaded chrome driver version is 77.0.3865.40. I'm still facing this issue.
I have downloaded the latest chrome driver as per my chrome browser version.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\kapil\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
String targetURL ="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in"; 
driver.get(targetURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Program for Launch Chrome Browser using Selenium Webdrive

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");

    // Initialize browser
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    // Open facebook
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    // Maximize browser

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    }
```

if you look for multiple tap and found it from [here](https://www.testingexcellence.com/open-new-tab-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-java/)

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); // switch back to main screen        
    driver.get("https://www.news.google.com");
```